# Kubernetes env-file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

env.example

```
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_DATABASE=db
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_USER=user
```

I created secret

```
kubectl create secret generic prod-secrets --from-file=env.example
```

Specified secret in mysql yaml file

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql-container
        image: mysql:dev
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        envFrom:
          - secretRef:
             name: prod-secrets
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
         # container (pod) path
        volumeMounts:
          - name: mysql-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /data/db
```

Pod goes into `CrashLoopBackOff`

This is from `kubectl describe pod`

> Environment Variables from:
>
> prod-secrets  Secret  Optional: false
>
> Environment:

What's wrong with this setup ?

Secret output:

```
kubectl describe secret prod-secrets
Name:         prod-secrets
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
env.example:  96 bytes
```

**EDIT**

After trying suggestion from answer, pod still crashing

```
mysql-container-ffdc44fc6-w9qqm     0/1     Error     1          23s
mysql-container-ffdc44fc6-w9qqm     0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          34s
mysql-container-ffdc44fc6-w9qqm     1/1     Running            2          34s
mysql-container-ffdc44fc6-w9qqm     0/1     Error              2          44s
mysql-container-ffdc44fc6-w9qqm     0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2          56s
mysql-container-ffdc44fc6-w9qqm     1/1     Running            3          72s
mysql-container-ffdc44fc6-w9qqm     0/1     Error              3          82s
```

Secret is shown correctly

```
kubectl describe secret prod-secrets
Name:         prod-secrets
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
MYSQL_DATABASE:       7 bytes
MYSQL_PASSWORD:       8 bytes
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  8 bytes
MYSQL_USER:           4 bytes
```

I'm running only 1-node cluster (1 master node), can this cause this issue ?

Found and issue:

specified root as DB_USER in env file, once i changed it all started working

Comment: output of kubectl describe secret prod-secrets

Comment: just posted it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the secret using the option **--from-env-file**

```
kubectl create secret prod-secrets \
       --from-env-file=env.example
```